# Chart.js totally local mode

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I recently discovered the possibility of easily creating charts thanks to the Chart.js library. I have added the necessary elements to my test site to evaluate the library using the online link, and everything works correctly.

The problem arises when I attempt to use the entire Chart.js library locally.

I followed the guide on the official website:

1. Installation in the correct directory using "npm."
2. Modification of the package.json file.
3. Modification of the index.html file to add the library locally
   using:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js"></script>
   ```
4. Installation and addition of the required Moment.js library:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>
   ```

Here is the index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>MoNKER</title>

      <script type = "text/javascript" src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <script type = "text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src="node_modules/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <style>
          .col-mon {
              text-align: center;
              border: 4px solid #ccc;
              padding: 10px;
              margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
          }
          .col-logo {
            text-align: right;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
          }
      </style>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end text-bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">
              <div class="offcanvas-header">
                <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">Dark offcanvas</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="offcanvas-body">
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex mt-3" role="search">
                  <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="col-logo">
            <img class="logo" src="img/monker.png" width="250px" height="auto">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="col-mon">
                <h2>Air</h2>
              <canvas id="airChart"> </canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="col-mon">
                <h2>CAMs</h2>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var airData = {
    labels: ['Tempo 1', 'Tempo 2', 'Tempo 3', 'Tempo 4', 'Tempo 5'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Kw 50',
            data: [40, 10, 50, 200, 20],
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        },
        {
            label: 'Kw 100',
            data: [20, 30, 40, 50, 80],
            borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        },
    ],
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('airChart').getContext('2d');
var airChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: airData,
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

This is the image of the file path and files (excluding the "old" and "img" folders:

[image: This is the image of the file path and files (excluding the "old" and "img" folders)]

Therefore, I assume it is solely a configuration issue with the library. Thanks in advance.

As I mentioned before, I have tried both online and offline modes, and the former works, while the latter does not. Despite working with HTML and JavaScript for a short period, I might be making a mistake in the installation of packages.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using "node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js" you have to make sure your server can access those files to be served, but serving files in node modules... that's a bad idea due security reasons.

Using a bundler, like rollup could fix this problem, bundling all your js files in a single file that could be put on your sources directory and provided by your server

In the docs, its specified that you should use the umd.js file:  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#script-tag